# Should null ever be used?

Tags: java, null, coding-style

I've recently read a few books on *clean code* and *refactoring*, and especially the former tend to advise the reader to neither return `null`, nor to pass it into any function (foreign, (for you) immutable code, such as the official libraries or external frameworks, excluded). See for example *Robert C. Martin - Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship*, pages 110-112 (6th printing).

From my experience, this generally makes sense. Instead of `null`, you can usually either throw an exception, return an empty list or array, or use some creative solution to avoid the possibility of a `NullPointerException`. Granted, you might then have to catch your own exceptions - but that's still more expressive than a generic `NullPointerException`.

I then thought about whether you should maybe avoid `null` entirely - i.e. not just in function calls or return statements, but *everywhere*. And from what I can tell, this should be both possible and reasonable.
However - still being a student - I am not entirely sure if that assumption / guideline is always correct. Therefore my question:

**Should you always try to avoid using `null` at any cost? Or are there cases where using it would be the more practical solution, despite the risk of `NullPointerExceptions`? Ignoring cases where you have to deal with foreign code that you can't influence, such as the official libraries.**

Comment: I can see why you would vote to close this as "primarily opinion-based". However, a simple counter-example would be sufficient to answer the question with "No". Just because a question cannot be backed up with a link to the oracle docs doesn't mean it's not a valid question.

Comment: "External APIs excluded"-- why exclude external APIs?  What is different between an external API and an internal one?  (Hint: nothing.)  If it's ok for an external API, it's ok for an internal one.  `null` should generally be avoided, but not "at any cost."  That is clearly excessive.

Comment: the difference is that, if an external API returns `null`, then I can't do **** about it. I can, however, avoid using `null` in my own code.

Comment: No, that's not right.  If it's fine for an external API to use it, then it's OK for an internal one.  There's no real difference.

Comment: @markspace well, it's **not** okay for an external API to use it. I just can't do anything about it, so if the framework method I'm using returns null, I'll have to deal with it.

Comment: You might want to check whether questions about best practices are on topic on [softwareengineering.se], and ask there instead if it is.

Comment: @Dukeling valid point - I wasn't aware of that stack exchange site (there's just too many :D). Can questions be moved to other stack exchange sites?

Comment: But that's wrong.  It **IS** OK for an API to use null values, that's why so many do so.  Your attempts to justify your position--that use of `null` is wrong--are unreasonable and clearly contradicted by current practice.

Comment: @PixelMaster [You can "migrate" questions by flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site) (assuming whichever mod looks at it agrees that it would be on topic there).

Comment: @markspace sure, many people use null. Many people also use comments instead of small methods and readable names, or they have duplicate code, none or at least bad tests, and name their variables `a`, `b` or `c`. If they wouldn't do these things, then there would be no reason for literature about `clean code` to even exist.

Comment: @PixelMaster What's wrong with comments? there's theory then there is experience and real complex systems with constraints. Regarding null, there's a broad range of situations where you need to return null and let the client decide what they should do with your return, being an exception throwing or a specific processing or...

Comment: @MehdiB. comments are not wrong per se. However, in many cases comments are used in place of good method names, which makes them redundant and reduces the readability of the code. I recommend reading literature about `clean code` which discusses this topic more in-depth than would be appropriate for this site.

Comment: In general you can and should avoid null, however, if avoiding null makes the code harder to maintain and read, you should probably just use it. There are a few rare instances particularly in Android programming where null can used to denote that an object has yet to be initialized or an action hasn't been taken by the user to set it, and some default action needs to be performed, and this seems cleaner than throwing in a bunch of boolean flags that aren't directly linked to the object or writing a more complex solution.

Comment: @Dukeling over there it would likely be closed as a duplicate of [Are null references really a bad thing?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/12777/31260) or one of dozen questions linked to it (and probably additionally voted down for the lack of research effort)

Comment: @PixelMaster I've just came across this coincidently https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions :D

Answer (score 5):

I think generally you should probably avoid using it, but I think it could have some uses for memory management. For example you may want to set some short lived objects to `null` when you are done with them to signal to the garbage collector that you want that memory cleaned up.

Comment: Setting a field to `null` to make the object faster eligible to be collected by the GC is often a misleading approach that can be broken with code changes. Reduce the scope of the created objects by refactoring the code (split the processings in two methods for example) is very often a better approach.  Besides, JVM optimiztions may also detect that a local variable is not any longer used in subsequent statements and may so do that eligible to be collected.

Comment: @davidxxx I think under most circumstances I would agree with you. I could see however that in some situations refactoring the code into another method may not be ideal depending on the situation.

Comment: @davidxxx overall I think the take away from this answer is that the `null` reference should be avoided in 99% of the situations you come across, however there may be some edge cases that permit it.

Answer (score 2):

It is more opinion based, but since the language specifications allows for the usage of `null` and the existence of native methods returning `null` e.g. [`HashMap#get(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)) it is not feasible to avoid it entirely.

Comment: as mentioned - "external APIs excluded". I counted the official libraries into those, but I will edit my question to make that clearer.

Comment: @PixelMaster Regardless of whether you include the standard API in your question, it makes use of null's, so obviously it's not such a bad idea (at least in the opinion of the API designers at the time).

Comment: @Dukeling java is over 20 years old. Just because something seemed like a good idea decades ago, doesn't mean it still is. Modern IDEs and libraries provide way more functionality than 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is used to initialize mutable objects....

Comment: yes, it is. But should it? That's the question.

Comment: Yes , its not mandatory as every object is initially null, you are right but you can use it just to maintain standards and to increase readibility of code.....